# ArgumentError: Unknown key: :through.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

モデルにおけるリレーションでthroughにエラーが起きます。

ArgumentError: Unknown key: :through. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class..

エラーでググったのですが、throughがkeyとして認識されていないというような記事は見当たりませんでした。

(User)モデルから(Article)モデルに中間テーブル(Review)を介して、リレーションをしようと

`model/user.rb`
`has_many :articles, through: :reviews`

このような形で指定しています。

原因が分からず。よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実際に使っている user.rb 、 review.rb 、 article.rb のコードをそのまま載せてください。
どこかに間違いや特殊な設定が隠れているのかもしれません。（関連の定義に別名を使っている等）

通常であれば次のようなコードになっていれば普通に動くはずです。

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :articles, through: :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :users, through: :reviews
end
```

Comment: こんにちは。いつも回答ありがとうございます。
おかげさまで解決いたしました！
私は１人のユーザーが複数の記事を所有することに対して、１つの記事が所有するユーザーは１人だと考えていました。
なので、Article.rbにbelongs_to :userと指定していましたが、そこをhas_many :userに変更したところ、うまくいきました。

正直私の考えでthroughが機能しなかったのかはよく分かってないです。
ありがとうございます！！

Comment: 解決したのであれば良かったです！僕の回答で問題なければ回答の承認を行ってください。承認すると他のユーザーが「あ、解決済みなんだな」ということがひと目でわかるようになるので！ http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers